# How to resolve MDF and LDF files remaining in use?

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2000

I am attempting to copy off approximately 220 gigs of database MDF and LDF files from a MS SQL server 2000 install in order to transfer ownership to a third party.

The error I get when I try to stop the database using the enterprise manager is

> Error 1051: A Stop Control Has Been Sent To A Service Which Other Running Services Are Dependent On

Going to the service and looking at the dependencies tab does not show any other services running in relation to it. If I stop the actual Windows service, and try to copy it tells me that the databases are still in use. I have changed the service from automatic to manual and rebooted, and it still insists the files are in use.

I don't particularly care about copying the log files, but how can I resolve the error to do a clean shutdown and be able to copy off at least the MDF files?

Comment: Space may be an issue with 220GB, but why not just do a normal SQL backup to a single file and transfer that?

Comment: The sysinternals Handle utility will report on which process has the files open. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle

Comment: [Find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows)

Comment: @BlueGI can you back up multiple databases at the same time to a single file? Or is it individual backups?

Comment: @JohnP Sure, you can add multiple and different DBs to a single backup file.  It's not necessarily good practice, but it's possible.  Using the UI is easiest, but if you want to script it, take a look at [Backup Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Just make sure not to INIT on subsequent calls.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin - I got a copy of process explorer, and found that sqlserver is the only one listed. Shut that down (again) and killed the process, still locked and procexp claims it's open by a process not in the list.

Comment: I've had success with this: I completely shut down the two related VM's, restarted the SQL Server VM, set the sql service to disabled and restarted again. This has allowed me to copy the files off.

Answer (score 0):

The Restart-Service cmdlet sends a stop message and then a start message to the Windows Service Controller for a specified service. If you specify -force parameter, it means override restrictions that prevent the command from succeeding,  e.g. stop and restart a service that has dependent services.

However, Windows Server manager launched via services.msc you mentioned is not running with force parameter when you click restart button there.

Thus if you want to do that, either stop the dependent services first, then retry or use the PowerShell command line to restart.